# Handling multipart/formdata and json payloads with Express?

Tags: json, express, multipartform-data

I have an express server that handles json payloads (using [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#readme)). It's a pretty standard setup:

```
const app = express();

...

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

...

app.post('/api/v1/login', usersController.login);
...etc
```

But now I have one query - a hook from an outside service - that's submitting data to me as `multipart/formdata`. How do I deal with those? Do I have to rejigger my entire setup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [connect-multiparty](https://github.com/expressjs/connect-multiparty) package.

An option could be like this (more specific):

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
app.post('/api/v1/login', multipart(), function(req, resp) {
  console.log(req.files); // in req.files are the files
});
```

Or just:

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
app.use(multipart());
```